# Where are the Manifest Configurations in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, location, codeblocks, manifest

I can't find them anywhere and nobody has answered before.

Please help

Comment: How is this question related to C++?

Comment: What do you call a manifest configuration?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "manifest configuration"?
There is a configuration file (xml) `default.conf` located in `C:\users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks`